# flutter not giving snapshot length and accessing snapshot data

Tags: flutter, api

I am fetching data from rest API and tried to build.I tried to find snapshot length but got an error

**The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try importing the library that defines 'length', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'length'**

I set itemCount value to default 1 and call my API and tried to build but got an error
**The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'**

the FutureBuilder code:

```
FutureBuilder(future:fetchPost(),builder: ((context, snapshot) {
            return ListView.builder(itemCount:snapshot.data!.length,itemBuilder: (context,index){
              return  ListTile(
                title: Text(snapshot.data![index].status),
              );
            });
          }),
          )
```

The data from my API:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e902",
        "userId": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
        "posts": [
            {
                "postType": "image",
                "post": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg",
                "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e903"
            },
            {
                "postType": "image",
                "post": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg",
                "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e904"
            }
        ],
        "status": "testing status",
        "comments": [
            {
                "commentText": "Testing comment",
                "commentAt": "2022-08-23T14:41:55.646Z",
                "commentReplys": [
                    {
                        "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                        "replyText": "Testing comment",
                        "replyAt": "2022-08-23T14:41:55.646Z",
                        "replyLikes": [
                            {
                                "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                                "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e907"
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e906"
                    },
                    {
                        "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                        "replyText": "reply text testing",
                        "replyAt": "2022-08-23T15:57:51.259Z",
                        "_id": "6304f90191c32e0deac663b8",
                        "replyLikes": []
                    }
                ],
                "commentLikes": [],
                "commentId": "bc174de0-22f1-11ed-9c5d-23d89a83ff32",
                "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e905"
            },
            {
                "commentText": "Testing comment",
                "commentAt": "2022-08-23T15:02:11.123Z",
                "commentId": "90928740-22f4-11ed-b912-e99836187b6d",
                "_id": "6304ec67825b5926f0f074cf",
                "commentReplys": [
                    {
                        "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                        "replyText": "reply text testing",
                        "replyAt": "2022-08-23T15:57:51.259Z",
                        "_id": "6304f90191c32e0deac663b8",
                        "replyLikes": []
                    }
                ],
                "commentLikes": []
            },
            {
                "commentText": "Testing comment",
                "commentAt": "2022-08-23T15:02:11.123Z",
                "commentId": "90928740-22f4-11ed-b912-e99836187b6d",
                "_id": "6304ec81825b5926f0f074d1",
                "commentReplys": [
                    {
                        "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                        "replyText": "reply text testing",
                        "replyAt": "2022-08-23T15:57:51.259Z",
                        "_id": "6304f90191c32e0deac663b8",
                        "replyLikes": []
                    }
                ],
                "commentLikes": []
            }
        ],
        "likes": [
            {
                "userId": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
                "_id": "63052dc7a1728d463769681b"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

fetchPost method:

```
 Future<Posts> fetchPost()async{
    final response=await http.get(Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2:8000/posts"));
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
    final posts=jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    return Posts.fromJson(posts);
    }
    else{
      print("error!");
      throw new Exception("error!");
    }
   }
```

How to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add the fetchPost method

Comment: ok i will add...

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the type parameter for the FutureBuilder

```
FutureBuilder<Posts>( // type Posts in your case
  future:fetchPost(),
  builder: ((context, snapshot) {

  })
)
```